# pandas query for string returns empty result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame imported with read_csv, as in this sample, but when i use query to filter the content i get an empty result.

The expected result i'm looking to get from query is row 0 and 2.

(pandas v1.3.1, python v3.9)

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Dorin\Desktop\folder_files\test_1.txt',
              encoding='utf-8',
              sep=';',
              names=["i_line", "f_path", "f_type", "f_hash"],
              dtype={'i_line': 'string', 'f_path': 'string', 'f_type': 'string', 'f_hash': 'string'},
              keep_default_na=False,
              na_values=['_'],
              index_col=False)
```

DataFrame `print(df1)`

```
  i_line        f_path f_type f_hash
0   i: 1   "content 1"      d    n/a
1   i: 2   "content 2"      f   1111
2   i: 3   "content 3"      d    n/a
```

Result of query `print(df1.query("f_hash == 'n/a'"))`

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [i_line, f_path, f_type, f_hash]
Index: []
```

File content

[image]

Comment: Can you post the content of the file? Is "n/a" text or the `numpy.NaN` object?

Comment: File content, 3 rows, content separated by semicolon ```i: 1; "content 1"; d; n/a;
i: 2; "content 2"; f; 1111;
i: 3; "content 3"; d; n/a;```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your file, the separator is not `;` but rather `;`  (with an optional space).

Thus your `n/a` is in fact a  `n/a`

You have to change the separator in `read_csv`:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('/tmp/t.csv',
              encoding='utf-8',
              sep='; ?',  ## sep is ";" with optional space
              names=["i_line", "f_path", "f_type", "f_hash"],
              dtype={'i_line': 'string', 'f_path': 'string', 'f_type': 'string', 'f_hash': 'string'},
              keep_default_na=False,
              na_values=['_'],
              index_col=False)
```